# Regex Extract Lat and Long from GPGGA String

Tags: java, regex

I have a GPS logger outputting GPGGA Strings, for example
     `$GPGGA,1714.0,3723.465874,N,12202.26954,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F`

The string is comma delimited. Working in Java, I am trying to extract the location information. Could someone help me with the required Regex statements

- `3723.465874` Between the 2nd and 3rd comma
- `N` Between the 3rd and 4th comma
- `12202.26954` Between the 4th and 5th comma
- `W` Between the 5th and 6th comma

Or, perhaps just one example, so I can infer the others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a clean delimiter, you can use `String.split`, like this:

```
String data = "$GPGGA,1714.0,3723.465874,N,12202.26954,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F";
String[] parts = data.split(",");
String p2 = parts[2]; // 3723.465874
String p3 = parts[3]; // N
String p4 = parts[4]; // 12202.26954
String p5 = parts[5]; // W
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/ksCQGC)

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string on the comma, then get the appropriate parts from the resulting string array.

```
String gpgga = 
   "$GPGGA,1714.0,3723.465874,N,12202.26954,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F"
String[] parts = gpgga.split(",");
String latitude = parts[2];
String nb = parts[3];
String longitude = parts[4];
String ew = parts[5];
```

Comment: Certainly a much better solution that my proposed method, and an essential addition to my Java knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/javisantana/1326141):

```
package es.agroguia.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class NMEA {

    class GPSPosition {
        public float time = 0.0f;
        public float lat = 0.0f;
        public float lon = 0.0f;
        public boolean fixed = false;
        public int quality = 0;
        public float dir = 0.0f;
        public float altitude = 0.0f;
        public float velocity = 0.0f;

        public void updatefix() {
            fixed = quality > 0;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("POSITION: lat: %f, lon: %f, time: %f, Q: %d, dir: %f, alt: %f, vel: %f", lat, lon, time, quality, dir, altitude, velocity);
        }
    }

    GPSPosition position = new GPSPosition();

    private static final Map<String, SentenceParser> sentenceParsers = new HashMap<String, SentenceParser>();

    public NMEA() {
        sentenceParsers.put("GPGGA", new GPGGA());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPGGL", new GPGGL());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPRMC", new GPRMC());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPRMZ", new GPRMZ());
        //only really good GPS devices have this sentence but ...
        sentenceParsers.put("GPVTG", new GPVTG());
    }

    public GPSPosition parse(String line) {

        if(line.startsWith("$")) {
            String nmea = line.substring(1);
            String[] tokens = nmea.split(",");
            String type = tokens[0];
            //TODO check crc
            if(sentenceParsers.containsKey(type)) {
                sentenceParsers.get(type).parse(tokens, position);
            }
            position.updatefix();
        }

        return position;
    }
}
interface SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String [] tokens, GPSPosition position);
}

    // utils
    static float Latitude2Decimal(String lat, String NS) {
        float med = Float.parseFloat(lat.substring(2))/60.0f;
        med +=  Float.parseFloat(lat.substring(0, 2));
        if(NS.startsWith("S")) {
            med = -med;
        }
        return med;
    }

    static float Longitude2Decimal(String lon, String WE) {
        float med = Float.parseFloat(lon.substring(3))/60.0f;
        med +=  Float.parseFloat(lon.substring(0, 3));
        if(WE.startsWith("W")) {
            med = -med;
        }
        return med;
    }

    // parsers 
    class GPGGA implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String [] tokens, GPSPosition position) {
            position.time = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            position.lat = Latitude2Decimal(tokens[2], tokens[3]);
            position.lon = Longitude2Decimal(tokens[4], tokens[5]);
            position.quality = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
            position.altitude = Float.parseFloat(tokens[9]);
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String input = "$GPGGA,1714.0,3723.465874,N,12202.26954,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\$GPGGA,[\\d\\.]*,([\\d\\.]+),([NS]),([\\d\\.]+),([EW]),.*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for(int i=0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + " = " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
    }
```

Output:

```
Group 0 = $GPGGA,1714.0,3723.465874,N,12202.26954,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F
Group 1 = 3723.465874
Group 2 = N
Group 3 = 12202.26954
Group 4 = W
```